# Using Sharpnado.Tabs get error "Invalid generic arguments (Parameter 'typearguments')"

Tags: c#, tabs, maui

I have a MAUI app that uses Community Toolkit MVVM nuget and Shell Navigation. I am currently trying to implement Sharpnado.Tabs but I can't find the solution to my issues.
This is how I have my project right now, my code is based on [Sharpnado.Tabs / MauiSample / MainPage](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs/blob/main/MauiSample/MainPage.xaml).

Navigation order:

1. LoginPage
2. TabbedPage:

   - MessagesPage
   - MorePages..

**AppShell.xaml**

```
<Shell
  x:Class="NewScholarApp.AppShell"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NewScholarApp"
  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:NewScholarApp.Views"
  Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

   <ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate vm:HomeTabbedPage}" Route="Home" />

</Shell>
```

**LoginPageViewModel** (this is working fine)

```
private async void Login()
{
   App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
}
```

**AppShell.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(HomeTabbedPage), typeof(HomeTabbedPage));
    }
}
```

**HomeTabbedPage** (The one that contains Sharpnado.Tabs)

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="NewScholarApp.Views.HomeTabbedPage"
              xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:NewScholarApp.Views"
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:NewScholarApp.ViewModels"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NewScholarApp"
            xmlns:tabs="http://sharpnado.com"
            BackgroundColor="#00928A"
             Title="HomeTabbedPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BottomTab" TargetType="tabs:BottomTabItem">
                <Setter Property="SelectedTabColor" Value="Gray" />
                <Setter Property="UnselectedLabelColor" Value="#00928A" />
                <Setter Property="LabelSize" Value="36" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansExtraBold" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="16,0" RowDefinitions="120,*,95">

        <tabs:ViewSwitcher x:Name="Switcher" Margin="0" Animate="True" Grid.RowSpan="3" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedViewModelIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <tabs:LazyView x:TypeArguments="local:MainPage" Animate="True"/>

        </tabs:ViewSwitcher>

        <tabs:TabHostView Grid.Row="2" CornerRadius="30" IsSegmented="True" Orientation="Horizontal" TabType="Fixed" SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={x:Reference Switcher}, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <tabs:BottomTabItem Style="{StaticResource BottomTab}" Label="M" />
        </tabs:TabHostView>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The error that I am having is when trying to navigate to HomeTabbedPage (Sharpnado tabs) is shows:
*System.ArgumentException has been thrown:*
*Invalid generic arguments (Parameter 'typearguments')*

Pointing to InitializeComponent() of my HomeTabbedPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class HomeTabbedPage : ContentPage
{
    public HomeTabbedPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Any help or information would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `x:TypeArguments="local:MainPage"`: requires `MainPage.xaml`. Do you have one in your project? Or should that have a different page name?

Comment: Hi, yes, I do have a MainPage in my project, that is the default screen when you create the project. I tried with MainPage, to avoid issues caused by any code in my page (MessagesPage).

Comment: And you've kept that in the root folder of project, so that `local:` is the correct namespace? Did not move it to `Views` subfolder?

Comment: That's correct, my MainPage is in the root folder, just like when you create a defalut project, this error happens with any Page, MainPage that is in root folder and my MessagesPage that is in Views subfolder. Have you used Sharpnado.Tabs before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharpnado Tabs only supports ContentView not ContentPage as tabs! You must put your tabs on MainPage and create views for each tab, including your homepage(view).

Comment: Thank you, so what is the best aproach to have differente contentviews binded to different viewmodels? like they were pages.

Comment: I currently use Sharpnado in my app and I bind all my viewmodels via Xaml - I don't use the xaml.cs method because it messes with my dependency injection. I get parameter errors within Sharpnado. If you have to use params then you'd need an injection service.

The only shell navigation necessary would be to navigate through pages in the app, not using Sharpnado.